# Error when pressing ENTER key in JComboBox dropdownlist

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I have a Java application and I'm using Netbeans IDE in creating GUI, the problem is 
I  always get this Error message whenever I pressed the ENTER key in choosing item in `JComboBox` drop down list.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicComboBoxUI.java:1554)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1639)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2851)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2897)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2814)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.processKeyEvent(JComboBox.java:1397)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6065)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1850)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:712)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:990)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:855)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:676)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4523)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

here is the pre-generated code in netbeans the initComponets() method is being called in the 
contructor

```
public class MyUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{

private javax.swing.JComboBox cboxAppName;

public MyUI(){
     initComponents();
}
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            new MainUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {
cboxAppName = new javax.swing.JComboBox(); 
cboxAppName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
cboxAppName.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item   2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
cboxAppName.setEditor(null);
cboxAppName.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cboxAppNameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    cboxAppName.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            cboxAppNameKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });
}
 private void cboxAppNameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        System.out.println(evt.getKeyChar());
    }
}

private void cboxAppNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println(evt.getSource());
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: Could you post the code relevant to the `JComboBox`?

Comment: @gla3dr  That's what a MCTaRE is all about.